# Time series analysis with non-stationary count data (Poisson/Negative binomial models)

Tags: time-series, stationarity, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, lags

I am trying to model the relationship between real-world events and specific features present in tweets related to these events. Whereas my dependent variable (events) is a count variable and its time series is non-stationary, the independent variable is stationary. Therefore, the variables aren't cointegrated either.
As far as I know, I can model either cointegrated or stationary time series. Furthermore, ARIMA modeling also assumes Gaussian distribution, hence, I'm not sure how I should determine the right number of lags of the two variables.

I am about to use the tscount R package, but if I differentiate the count variable to make it stationary, it won't follow a Poisson/Negative binomial distribution anymore, e.g. it will take negative values as well. Moreover, I'm not sure if differentiating a variable and then estimating a regression with log link (like most count models) would make sense, because the log of the difference between values in t2 and t1 will just simply be the growth rate in the events. Hence, my model would signal spurious autocorrelations.

I was also thinking about modeling time dynamics with a random intercept model like:
glmmTMB(event ~ tweet_feature +
(1|date),
data=daily_data,
family=poisson)
but then I don't know how to take into account the autoregressive nature of the time series (e.g. how to calculate Granger causality, but also, how many lagged variables should I add). Or should I just add lagged versions of the two variables as long as they're significant?

Does anyone have any experience with such models?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your second sentence is self-contradictory; is the dependent variable stationary or nonstationary?

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed the typo. Thank you!